# Why initializing a property doesn't work?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
class Log
{
    private $mode = config('my.log.mode');
}
```

but it throws *syntax error* ..! Why? what's wrong?

Noted that this works as well:

```
class Log
{
    private $mode;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->mode = config('my.log.mode');
    }
}
```

well, what's the point?!

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize properties with constant values only. So, you can't use `config()` or any other helper here.

> Initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: ..or a scalar expression as of PHP 5.6: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.const-scalar-exprs